# Testing Text-Based Emails

Tags: google-app-engine, email, html-email

I am using Google AppEngine API to send an email to my application's users. The email fields accepts *html* and *body*, where the former is the HTML version of the email and the latter is the plain text form. I can easily test the HTML version (to see how it looks) by sending an email to myself. But I am wondering how I can test the plain text version if all of the email providers nowadays are HTML based?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send an email to yourself, then view the source. In GMail, for instance, you do this by clicking on the down arrow in the upper right corner of the message, then clicking "Show Original".

Comment: Are you sure that would help? I thought the email is sent based on the recipient server. If it supports html, it sends the html version, otherwise, it sends the text version.

Comment: @Promather No, there's no way to determine in advance what the client will support. Emails are sent with both HTML and text parts, in a MIME multipart message. Clients display whichever one they are capable of showing.